# Find the internal bending moment, Mc

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, civil-engineering, structural-analysis, stresses

A 7meter,m, long cantilever beam whose weight per meter is 19Newton, N, carries a load that varies uniformly from 43N/m, (Newton/meter), at the inbuilt side, point A, to 0 at the free end, point B. Find the internal bending moment, Mc, at a point C located 1meter,m, from point A

Answer (score 0):

You shall have tried yourself. The figure below will refresh your memory of what have learned at school.

[image]

Now, just for the sake of fun, work out this problem from the free end towards point "C" and see what results.